# Cisco Standalone AP reduce signal strength

Tags: wireless-access-point

I have a Cisco AP model : AIR-SAP1602I-E-K9 and have a problem where the signal strength is too high. I have searched for a way to reduce tx power to reduce the signal strength and found the command `power local <level>` under the interface configuration for the dot11radio but it does not seem to affect the signal strength at all.

I have been using an android app called inSSIDer to monitor the signal strength and I do not see any difference when testing the four different power levels available (16 13 10 7). How can I reduce the signal strength such that the range of the AP is shortened? I am running IOS 15.2(4).